# How do I log in as a different user when there isn't a login link on the front page?

Tags: users

I created a user with limited rights and logged in as that user.

Now I have discovered that I have not placed a login module on the front page.

How do I log back in as administrator?

Comment: Go to yourdomain/user

Answer (score 0):

Click logout - *usually* in the top right corner (but may vary depending on theme); `/user/logout` is the address.

Then log back in (from `/user`) with your administrator credentials.

Comment: thanks very much for your response.

from here?
http://www.southark.edu/conferencecenter/user

I don't see a place to do that.  What am I missing?